# Determine designtime in Eclipse / WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm creating controlls to use with `WindowBuilder Pro`. Is there a possibility to detect design mode in `Eclipse`?

**Example what i want to do in my control:**

```
if(designmode) {
   loadDummyValues();
}else{
   loadRealComplexRuntimeValues();
}
```

In Netbeans its determined like this:

```
java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime()
```

So i hope there is also a possibility for `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found it myself, @Ahmed Ekri pointed me in the right direction, to look specifically for a notion for `WindowBuilder`:

```
    if (Beans.isDesignTime()) {
        //Designtime
        [...]
    } else {
        //Runtime
        [...]
    }
```

More details can be read [here](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/faq#CustomWidgets).

Answer (score 2):

> Eclipse itself does not have a notion of design time nor has it any 
>   special support for JavaBeans-based development. Maybe the Eclipse
>   Visual  Editor does.

try this link [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/?group=eclipse.tools.ve)